# Can I enable FFI by default without shell-escape?

Tags: luatex, texlive, shell-escape, ffi

The FFI library included in `luatex` could be dangerous so it is disabled by default (at least in TeXLive). In order to access the library, one has to invoke `luatex` with the `--shell-escape` option. Is there a way in TeXLive (a config file ?) to permanently allow the FFI library without the `shell-escape` option ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no option to allow FFI without allowing shell-escape because this would not be a useful restriction.

Since FFI allows you to access pretty much arbitrary C libraries, it especially allows you to directly execute the system library calls to run arbitrary commands. So once FFI is allowed, there is no longer any advantage in forbidding direct shell escape.

On the other hand TeX Live *does* allow you to enable shell escape and therefore also FFI by default: Find your local `texmf.cnf` (e.g. with `kpsewhich texmf.cnf`, the path should look like `.../texmf-local/web2c/texmf.cnf` or `.../2021/texmf.cnf`, do *not* edit the file under `texmf-dist`) and add a line:

```
# DANGER: Allow shell escape in all lualatex documents by default.
shell_escape.lualatex = t
```

Other options are  `= p` to allow only restricted commands (TeX Live's default) and  `= f` to disallow all kinds of shell escape. You can set `shell_escape` without `.lualatex` if you want to change the setting for all formats.

I recommend you not to do this. It is likely to lead to issues when working with others (since they now need other options to compile your files than you do) and it allows any document you compile to execute arbitrary commands on your system. If this is enabled, you have to make sure never to compile a document if you don't fully trust the document and all used packages/classes/... .